# mac terminal shows myname@192 instead of myname@myname-mac-pro

Tags: ssh, terminal

I was playing with some react project and kill some node on from ports. Then when i opened a new mac terminal, the default welcome line changed from

```
Last login: Tue Jun  1 6:49:47 on ttys000
name@name-macbook-pro ~ %
```

to

```
Last login: Tue Jun  1 6:49:47 on ttys000
name@192 ~ %
```

what does @192 mean?

Comment: That's most likely the first octet of your IP address: 192.168.something.something  Somehow that's got set as the hostname, instead of name-macbook-pro.something.something

Comment: yeah i thought of the same. but any idea how it happened and how to change it back?

Answer (score 15):

Type in Terminal:

```
scutil --get HostName
```

If there's no HostName available, what you see is probably coming from the DNS or DHCP server.

Set your HostName with:

```
sudo scutil --set HostName 'yourHostName'
```

That should do it.